# How to find in a many to many relation all the identical values in a column and join the table with other three tables?

Tags: postgresql, join, duplicates, many-to-many

I have a many to many relation with three columns, (owner_id,property_id,ownership_perc) and for this table applies (many owners  have many properties).

So I would like to find all the owner_id who has many properties (property_id) and connect them with other three tables (Table 1,3,4) in order to get further information for the requested result.
All the tables that I'm using are

```
Table 1: owner (id_owner,name)
Table 2: owner_property (owner_id,property_id,ownership_perc)
Table 3: property(id_property,building_id)
Table 4: building(id_building,address,region)
```

So, when I'm trying it like this, the query runs but it returns empty.

```
SELECT address,region,name
FROM owner_property
JOIN property ON owner_property.property_id = property.id_property
JOIN owner ON owner.id_owner = owner_property.owner_id
JOIN building ON property.building_id=building.id_building
GROUP BY owner_id,address,region,name
HAVING count(owner_id) > 1
ORDER BY owner_id;
```

Only when I'm trying the code below, it returns the owner_id who has many properties (see image below) but without joining it with the other three tables:

[image]

```
SELECT a.*
FROM owner_property a
JOIN (SELECT owner_id, COUNT(owner_id)
FROM owner_property
GROUP BY owner_id
HAVING COUNT(owner_id)>1) b
ON a.owner_id = b.owner_id
ORDER BY a.owner_id,property_id ASC;
```

So, is there any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong when I'm joining the tables? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT owner_id
FROM owner_property
GROUP BY owner_id
HAVING COUNT(property_id) > 1
```

returns all the `owner_id`s with more than 1 `property_id`s.
If there is a case of duplicates in the combination of `owner_id` and `property_id` then instead of `COUNT(property_id)` use `COUNT(DISTINCT property_id)` in the `HAVING` clause.
So join it to the other tables:

```
SELECT b.address, b.region, o.name
FROM (
  SELECT owner_id
  FROM owner_property
  GROUP BY owner_id
  HAVING COUNT(property_id) > 1
) t
INNER JOIN owner_property op ON op.owner_id = t.owner_id 
INNER JOIN property p ON op.property_id = p.id_property
INNER JOIN owner o ON o.id_owner = op.owner_id
INNER JOIN building b ON p.building_id = b.id_building
ORDER BY op.owner_id, op.property_id ASC;
```

Always qualify the column names with the table name/alias.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm trying what you have suggested me but it didn't recognise the op., for the table owner_property... ERROR:  column op.property_id does not exist
LINE 8: INNER JOIN property p ON op.property_id = p.id_property.

Comment: Correct, there was a missing join. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable help! The query runs perfectly!I was trying all day to figure it out!...I am quite new to SQL.Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a correlated subquery that counts the ownerships with `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT b1.address,
       b1.region,
       o1.name
       FROM owner_property op1
            INNER JOIN owner o1
                       ON o1.id_owner = op1.owner_id
            INNER JOIN property p1
                       ON p1.id_property = op1.property_id
            INNER JOIN building b1
                       ON b1.id_building = p1.building_id
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ''
                            FROM owner_property op2
                            WHERE op2.owner_id = op1.owner_id
                            HAVING count(*) > 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! I tried your suggestion and it returned empty. Also, I would like to mention that one owner may have many properties and different % of ownership for each property. So, I didn't understand how the column ownership_perc would help me to find the repeated owner_id, except from using count.